# Clone prop object into new data object

Tags: vue.js

**Base structure of Vue components;**

Users.Vue (parent component)
EditUserModal.vue (child component)

I have a data table of users, when the user selects a user, this data property gets updated with the selected user (inside Users.vue);

```
  selectedUser: {}
```

I have a modal component that takes the selected user in as a prop

```
<edit-user-modal :selected-user="selectedUser"></edit-user-modal>
```

The modal has a form that is updated with values based on the data sent in

**How i want the form to act** - i want the user to be able to edit the data on the form, the form will be pre filled based on the selected user

**My problem** - i want to clone the selected user prop into a new data object, so that when the user starts filling out the form, the cloned data object will get updated and not the prop

**What ive tried**

```
props: ['selectedUser'],
mounted() {
    if (!_.isEmpty(this.selectedUser)) {
        this.clonedUserObject = Object.assign({}, this.selectedUser)
    }
},
data() {
    return {
        clonedUserObject: {}
    }
},
```

**Also**

```
props: ['selectedUser'],
data() {
    return {
        clonedUserObject: Object.assign({}, this.selectedUser)
    }
},
```

Both times, the data property clonedUserObject has been empty when i select a user

Comment: Have you tried debugging this by checking the `mounted` hook? It's possible that when it runs, the `selectedUser` prop is empty. If that is the problem, you will need  a watcher to update the `clonedUserObject` whenever the prop changes. I can provide a full answer for that if needed.

Comment: Hi @dougalg, i will add a watcher and see if this helps, thanks!

Comment: I found using [Vue.set](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set) helps a lot when dealing with copying objects.

Comment: @dougalg, your solution worked for me. I haven't had to use a watcher before and wasn't sure how they worked until now, thank you

Comment: Glad to hear it! I have submitted an answer, if you could check it and mark it as accepted (or suggest changes if needed), I would appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely due to the prop not being ready at the time that `mounted` runs. This can be determined by checking via debug tools or `console.log` that the prop is populated or not at that time.

In this case, the solution is to use a watcher. For example:

```
watch: {
  selectedUser: {
    // This will make sure it picks up your prop if it is set at the start,
    // allowing you to fully remove the mounted hook
    immediate: true,
    // If you need to check if a single internal property of the selectedUser changed
    // also set deep: true
    deep: true,
    handler: (val) {
      this.clonedUserObject = Object.assign({}, val);
    }
  }

}
```